# Permanent solution for windows installer Error 1500

Tags: windows-installer

There is a very bad error telling you that another application is installing, when theres no such installation going on actually, and this error keeps coming after restart.
There is a solution but for every install involving deleting the registery key Inprogress, and stopping and starting the installer service, you have to do this which is really bad.
So, is there any permanent solution to this ?
http://www.appdeploy.com/msierrors/detail.asp?id=111

Comment: What is the scale of this issue for you? Are you seeing this one one machine or many machines?  Once or repeatedly?

Comment: I am using windows 7, and search enough on google for windows installer error 1500 for windows 7.

Comment: Something to check... In my case, I found the Java Platform SE Auto Updater (`jusched.exe`) was enabled on Startup. I wasn't certain if this was the conflict, but after disabling this startup item under System Configuration (`msconfig`), I was able to proceed with the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permanent solution is to apply all the updates for the windows 7. All other solutions need to be applied again and again.
But one must also know this http://www.appdeploy.com/msierrors/detail.asp?id=111

Answer (score 0):

In window 10, Press control + alt+ del

- Search Window Installer processes.
- End both Processes.
- Try to install the application again.

It was due to background downloading and installation/upgradation of other applications by windows.